# Array being deallocated after end of a c function?

Tags: c, scope, postgis

I have a function that I am passing a pointer to  then allocating memory inside the function.

```
count = rt_band_get_ray(band,x1,y1,x2,y2,&npixels);
```

Here is the function body:

```
/**
* Processes an array of pixels that fall on the ray from x1,y1 to x2,y2.
 * @param band : band to be processed
 * @param x1 : starting x-cordinate ( 0 based )
 * @param y1 : starting y-cordinate ( 0 based )
 * @param x2 : ending x-crodinate ( 0 based ) 
 * @param y2 : ending y-cordinate ( 0 based )
 * @param npixels : pointer to array of pixels
 * 
 * @return -1 on error 0 for sucess.
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm
 */
int 
rt_band_get_ray(rt_band band, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, rt_pixel *npixels )
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int xinc1;
  int yinc1;
  int xinc2;
  int yinc2;
  int dx;
  int dy;
  int den;
  int num;
  int numadd;
  int curpixel;
  double pixval;
  int isnodata = 0;
  rt_pixel pixel = NULL;
  int count;

  dx = abs( x2 - x1 );
  dy = abs( y2 - y1 );

  x = x1;
  y = y1;

  // considerations for all eight quads

  if ( x2 >= x1 )  // the x-values are increasing 
    {
      xinc1 = 1;
      xinc2 = 1;
    }
  else   // the x-values are decreasing
    {
    xinc1 = -1;
    xinc2 = -1;
    }

  if( y2 >= y1 ) // the y-values are increasing
    {
      yinc1 = 1;
      yinc2 = 1;
    }
  else  // the y-values are decreasing
    {
      yinc1 = -1;
      yinc2 = -1;
    }

  if ( dx >= dy )  // there is at least one x-value for every y-value
    {
      xinc1 = 0;   //don't change x when numerator >= denominator
      yinc2 = 0;   // don't change y for every iteration
      den = dx;
      num = dx / 2;
      numadd = dy;
      count = dx;  // there are more x-values than y-values
    }
  else
    {
      xinc2 = 0;
      yinc1 = 0;
      den = dy;
      num = dy / 2;
      numadd = dx;
      count = dy;
    }

  // allocate array
    if (npixels == NULL)
     *npixels = (rt_pixel) rtalloc(sizeof(struct rt_pixel_t) * count);
    else
     *npixels = (rt_pixel) rtrealloc(*npixels, sizeof(struct rt_pixel_t) * count);
    if (npixels == NULL) {
      rterror("rt_band_get_ray: Unable to allocate memory for ray pixel(s)");
      return -1;
    } 

  for ( curpixel = 0; curpixel < count; curpixel++)  //itterate through all pixels on the line
    {
      // set current pixel to array
      rt_band_get_pixel(band,x,y,&pixval,&isnodata);
      pixel = &((*npixels)[curpixel]);
      pixel->x = x;
      pixel->y = y;
      pixel->nodata = isnodata;
      pixel->value = pixval;

      num += numadd;  // increase the numerator by the top of the fraction
      if ( num >= den )  // check if numerator >= denominator
    {
      num -= den;  // calculate the new numerator value
      x += xinc1;  // change x as appropriate
      y += yinc1;  // change y as appropriate
    }
      x += xinc2;   // change x as appropriate
      y += yinc2;   // change y as appropriate
    }
  return count; // return number of npixel elements.

}
```

I think I am loosing scope on the memory allocated inside the function. And experiencing a segmentation fault. On these lines:

```
for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
      pixel = &((*npixels)[i]);
      results[i] =  pixel->value;
    }
```

Am I loosing scope, on the data allocated inside the function? If so how do I accomplish, allocating an array inside this function with out loosing scope?

Comment: how does this for loop fit in with the rest of the code?

Comment: What does 'rtalloc' do? Because according to manual, it 'looks up a route in the kernel table'. Most definitely however, it doesn't allocate any sort of memory. That's what 'malloc' is for.

Comment: Regarding memory management in C though: Every memory you manually allocate (with malloc), you'll have to dealloc with 'free' again. Otherwise, you'll leak memory, which can cause your program to crash eventually. And I don't see an 'array' in your function either. Just a pointer. (Whose content clearly doesn't get deallocated anywhere)

Comment: rtalloc:   Raster core memory management functions.

Wrappers used for managing memory.

They use the functions defined by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use pointer to pointer, so that you can change actual pointer value from inside the function. you func prototype should look like

```
int rt_band_get_ray(rt_band band, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
                    rt_pixel **p_npixels)
```

beware -- all the references inside the function to npixels should be changed to (*p_npixels), like in this example lines from your code:

```
if (npixels == NULL)
    *npixels = (rt_pixel) rtalloc(sizeof(struct rt_pixel_t) * count);
```

should become

```
if (*p_npixels == NULL)
    **p_npixels = (rt_pixel) rtalloc(sizeof(struct rt_pixel_t) * count);
```

and be called like

```
rt_pixel *npixels;

rt_band_get_ray(band, x1, y1, x2, y2, &npixels);
```

and after that code shoudl work fine

Comment: main idea was to inform you that passing pointer via stack makes local copy of it in called function, so assigning to the pointer will not be propagated to caller.
so you _must_ use pointer to pointer to make changes to pointer via pointer to that pointer you want to change inside called function (kind of kidding here, but if you parse this, it is correct). so that you know what to do, btw, i really isn't going to debug the code or something like that...

Comment: Thanks, for your help.. I tend to take things literally, and I know its not your place to debug my code. Again thanks.